# Is there a special status for the offspring of an animal that was dedicated for a Karban?

Tags: halacha, animals, pregnancy-birth, korban, hekdesh

For example, if someone in the time of the temple dedicated a cow for a Karban, and before they could bring it to be sacrificed it became pregnant (or impregnated another cow), would its calf have any special status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child of a Shelamim is offered as a Shelamim according to the Chachamim, while R Eliezer prohibits doing so. All further descendants of a Shelamim's child are not offered.

All descendants of a Todah are offered as Todot but without bread.

All descendants of a Bechor or a Maaser are treated as a Bechor or Maaser.

All descendants of a Chattat must die.

All descendants of a Temurat Olah are offered as an Olah.

All descendants of a female animal that was separated as an Olah should be left to graze until they get a blemish and then sold with the proceeds going to extra Temple offerings. R Eliezer holds that they may be offered as Olot themselves.

All descendants of a Temurat Asham should be left to graze until they get a blemish and then sold with the proceeds going to extra Temple offerings. R Elazar says you can use the funds for a personal voluntary Olah offering. According to R Eliezer they must die.

(Based on [Mishnah Temurah Chapter 3](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishna_Temurah.3). See also [Rambam Hilchot Temura Chapter 4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/9604.htm).)

Comment: The _mishna_ there seems to be talking about children of female animals. The question here is about children of any animals.