# Did Akeidat Yitzchak dedicate Yitzchak and his future offspring to Hashem?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, avot-patriarch-fathers, korban, binding-of-isaac, hekdesh

In the case of an animal that is intended to be brought as a korban, but the animal has offspring before being sacrificed, the offspring retains a special status. Depending on the type of Korban, the offspring must also be sacrificed or be allowed to graze until they become unfit for sacrifice. ([My related question & source.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31642/is-there-a-special-status-for-the-offspring-of-an-animal-that-was-dedicated-for))

This is similar to when Avraham brought Yitzchack up as a Korban to Hashem. Avraham's full-intention of sacrificing Yitzchak endowed him with the status of a Korban. Having been intended as Korban, Yitzchak's offspring would also retain that holy-status.

If what I'm saying is correct, this would give a purpose to Akeidat Yitzchak other than testing Avraham. Through the Akeida, Hashem elevated Yitzchak and ultimately, Yitzchak's offspring to a Korban-status and dedicated them to Hashem. This could also be why it was Yitzchak's right to pass the birthright to either Yaakov or Eisav, (and ultimately Bnei Yisroel).

**I like this idea and am wondering whether (a) any commentary or rabbi suggests it or (b) whether there is any flaw in it.**

Comment: You aren't asking a question.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I rewrote this a few times, but I'm not sure how to ask it. I guess I'm asking if anyone knows of a source that makes this comparison, or if what I'm saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: zaq, this question prompted me to post [this](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/heres-my-devar-torah-do-any-of-the-commentaries-say-this). I want you to know that I love this idea and the way you primed for it here with a not-obviously-related prior question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thanks for fixing the question, and I'm glad you like it.

Comment: How about Esav's descendants?

Comment: Sometimes Korban-animals can be  sold for money which is donated instead. Similarly, Eisav sold his birthright to Yaakov.